# Set Jquery Draggable text's top and left on mouse move?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

A custom grid whose items are draggable i.e. you can drag any row and drop it to the left tree structure.What i did for drggable is this

```
 $("#ulMyItemsNew").append(liItem).find("li").draggable({

                    helper: 'clone',
                    revert: function (event) {
                        //hides tooltip when not a valid drop
                        $(".tooltipProduct:visible").hide();
                        return !event;
                    },
                    cursor: 'move',
                    start: function (event, ui) {     

                        $(this).draggable("option", "cursorAt", {
                            left: event.pageX,
                            top: event.pageY 
                       });


                    },

                    zIndex: 507000
                });
```

Actually the thing is when i start dragging any row from Manufacturer then my mouse and the dragging text moves together.But when i start dragging from Model Number then my mouse and the dragging text gets distance.And when i start dragging from Description then my mouse and the dragging text gets more distance.What i want is , whether i drag from Manufacturer or Model Number or Description ,the dragging text should always move alongwith my mouse.There should be no distance in between them .

I know in the code area

```
 start: function (event, ui) {     

                        $(this).draggable("option", "cursorAt", {
                            left: event.pageX,
                            top: event.pageY 
                       });
                     }
```

i am doing `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` and the event is not the mouse move event rather it is the `draggable` text event.I did called a function also inside the "start" helper like this

```
    start: function (event, ui) {     

                           GetMousePosition();
    }

function GetMousePosition() {
 $("#ulMyItemsNew li.ui-draggable-dragging").mousemove(function (event) {

            var offset = $("#ulMyItemsNew li.ui-draggable-dragging").offset();


            $("#ulMyItemsNew li.ui-draggable-dragging").css({ left: event.pageX - offset.left, top: event.pageX - offset.top });


        });
}
```

But nothing works as i want `ulMyItemsNew` is the `ul` id under which all the `li` rows of the grid are present. `li.ui-draggable-dragging` is the class of that `draggable` text that gets appended dynamically at the bottom of `ul` .

Any help would be much appreciated . I am stuck in this from 2 weeks . Thanks in Advance !!

Here is the Snap Shot -

[image]

Comment: try adding this - `cursorAt: { left: 1, top:1 }` just above your `cursor:move` and remove everything from `start`. and why do have `zIndex:507000` try adding `100`.

Comment: if possible please create a fiddle of your code

Comment: Thanks @Shail Paras  . It worked .I removed everything from start and added cursorAt above as you said .It works fine . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this and it worked as i wanted .Now my cursor and the draggable "li" moves together.I didn't knew that the cursorAt helper actually sets the cursor top and left with respect to the draggable item.

```
$("#ulDragNew").append(liItem).find("li").draggable({
                    helper: 'clone',

                    cursorAt: {
                        left: 40,
                        top: 20
                    },

                    revert: function (event) {
                        //hides tooltip when not a valid drop
                        $(".tooltipProduct:visible").hide();
                        return !event;
                    },
                    cursor: 'move',



                    zIndex: 100
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have fixed the cursor position when you start dragging:

```
$(this).draggable("option", "cursorAt", {
                  left: event.pageX,
                  top: event.pageY 
               });
```

Thats why it is happening.

Using this-

```
cursorAt: { left: 1, top:1 }
```

option to specify another location relative to the draggable (specify a pixel value from the top, right, bottom, and/or left). Customize the cursor's appearance by supplying the cursor option with a valid CSS cursor value: default, move, pointer, crosshair, etc.

Check here for more detail

[draggable - cursor-style](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#cursor-style)

Comment: @TusharRaj - Is my answer not useful for you? or you find anyother solution. Please explain a little bit or post your answer so other can also see the right answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shail for your kind reply . Actually the thing is when i did
 $(this).draggable("option","cursorAt",{
                  left: 1,
                  top: 1
               });
Then it worked fine but only from the second dragging ...Initially for the first time when i drag then it behaves as it was (showing distance when dragging from the Model Number and more distance when dragging from the Description),so i just removed that "start" helper code as you said and added "cursorAt: { left: 1, top:1 }" which works for any time dragging as i wanted.

Comment: For "left:event.pageX and top:event.pageY" ,i think the "event" was that draggable "li" event and the mistake i did was putting pageX and pageY for that event which actually spoiling the required feature .Thanks a lot :)